# NServiceBus Compatibility

Tags: .net-4.0, compatibility, nservicebus

I'm trying to to send a Command from a .net 3.5 client machine to a .net 4 server machine.

What came to my mind is to install NSB 2 compiled with .net 3.5 on the client and NSB 2 compiled with .net 4 on the server. Do you know if it would work properly?  Any thing I need to watch out for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your using XML serialization, you should be fine.